# Android Studio: reliable collision detection

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

how to reliably detect collision between two rectangles on android?

I have tried two ways, the first basic collision:

```
// using android.graphics.Rect
//worldRects is an array of Rects containing only one Rect based off mapX and mapY
//playerRect is a stationary Rect in the middle of the screen slightly bigger than player
//sectorArrayX & Y and sector have to do with joystick and moving map accordingly

for (int ir = 0; ir < worldRects.length; ir++) {
  if (!Rect.intersects(playerRect, worldRects[ir])) {
     mapX = mapX + ((speed * (-1 * sectorArrayX[sector])) / fps);
     mapY = mapY + ((speed * (-1 * sectorArrayY[sector])) / fps);
   } 
}
```

this causes the player to become locked in position upon collision

my second attempt was trying to move player in opposite direction upon collision this works fairly well but occasionally will fail no matter how much I increase the "bounce back" amount.

```
for (int ir = 0; ir < worldRects.length; ir++) {
  if (!Rect.intersects(playerRect, worldRects[ir])) {
    mapX = mapX + ((speed * (-1 * sectorArrayX[sector])) / fps);
    mapY = mapY + ((speed * (-1 * sectorArrayY[sector])) / fps);
  } else {
    mapX = mapX + (25<-"bounce back amount" * (1 * sectorArrayX[sector])); 
    mapY = mapY + (25 * (1 * sectorArrayY[sector])); 
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do this in a very efficient manner, don't care much for accuracy really after a reliable method. Thanks in advance!

I've also included videos of both problems:

problem 1:
https://youtu.be/iB7hLZpS3hQ

problem 2:
https://youtu.be/k9oEA2s7e3E

Comment: Besides the solution is there any reason to not use a third party library for that? e.g. libGDX.